# Any pointers for creating Kafka endpoint support?

Tags: apache-kafka, citrus-framework

I have a fairly immediate need to support Kafka integration testing using the Citrus Framework. I was thinking of taking the existing jms module as an example/framework and using Spring Kafka. Any pointers or gotchas that I should be aware of? I am willing, assuming I'm successful, to donate the module back to the project.

Comment: This is something that I want to create for long time. Haven't had the time though. The Citrus team would love to receive some help here! So please contribute once you are done! As a starting point you can use the jms module as suggested. I think this is a good way to get started with a Kaftka endpoint. However it should be mentioned that you may also have a look at Apache Camel Kafka integration. You can use this Camel component out-of-the-box right now with Citrus, too. Nevertheless looking forward to a Kafka Citrus integration because it will be easier to configure within Citrus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use a Kafka Camel component with Citrus:

```
@Bean
    public CamelContext camelKafkaAdapterContext() throws Exception {
        SpringCamelContext context = new SpringCamelContext();
        context.addRouteDefinition(new RouteDefinition()
                .from("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=test&zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181&serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
                .to("log:com.consol.citrus.camel?level=DEBUG")
                .to("seda:kafka-buffer"));
        return context;
    }

    @Bean
    public CamelEndpoint kafkaEndpoint(CamelContext camelContext) {
        CamelEndpoint endpoint = new CamelEndpoint();
        endpoint.getEndpointConfiguration().setCamelContext(camelContext);
        endpoint.getEndpointConfiguration().setEndpointUri("seda:kafka-buffer");

        return endpoint;
    }
```

You first define a Camel Context which will be startet when you run any test with Citrus. After it is instantiated, this Camel component will read from the configured `topic` and send all messages into a buffer `seda:kafka-buffer` (*seda* is used only as an example). After which you can use a Citrus CamelEndpoint to read messages from that buffer inside any test.

```
receive(action -> action.endpoint(kafkaEndpoint)
                .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
                .payload(...);
```

Note, this is just an example I have assembled. I haven't tested this exact setup, but it will work once you configure the Camel Context correctly.